# Fragments not displaying

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have got 2 fragments and i have made a layout in the bottom part of the page as below

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.example.alsongdunstan.thefaithapp.ui.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"

                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Then i created an activity class that i would use as the activity from which i create the adapter for the view pager and also populating the view pager

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Here is where i populate the view pager from

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // adding filter list fragment
    filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();
    filtersListFragment.setListener(this);

    // adding edit image fragment
    editImageFragment = new EditImageFragment();
    editImageFragment.setListener(this);

    adapter.addFragment(filtersListFragment, getString(R.string.tab_filters));
    adapter.addFragment(editImageFragment, getString(R.string.tab_edit));

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is how my app looks like after doing all the above.

[image: Picture showing the final output from the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are added to activities by replacing a `ViewGroup` (usually `FrameLayout`) with an instance of the Fragment you want.

In your activity's layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your activity's Java code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.placeholder_fragment, new MyFragment())
    .commit();
```

Comment: and still getting the same output. The tab names show but not the fragments